# Who do the hands that help form Naruto's Final Rasengan belong to?

Tags: naruto

[Here is the video of Naruto's Final Rasengan in episode 477.](https://youtu.be/TtKh422U-aA)

The hands of many friends, [parents](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki), and [teachers](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jiraiya#cite_note-d4-3) of Naruto Uzamaki were shown shaping and enlarging together his [Rasengan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rasengan):

[image]

My questions are:

- **What is the meaning of this scene?**
- **What is the chronological list of characters of the *Naruto* universe who contributed to his Rasengan (with irrefutable evidence)?**

Comment: Your video link is dead.

Comment: Maybe you guys didn't notice, but Sasuke's Chidori has Itachi's hand on it. So it's obvious that the hands are from the people who made Sasuke and Naruto who they are today.

Comment: @JPak I recommend that you and ItachiUchiha have this conversation in a chat room (http://chat.stackexchange.com/) or on some external chat service rather than in the comments on this question.

Comment: @user.3710634,J.pak?Yop.Present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been going around Twitter for a while.

[image: Spirit Bomb Rasengan ver]

This is more or less Naruto's version of the DBZ Spirit Bomb trope where you borrow the spirit of all your allies into one final coup-de-grace. Then hands represented are as follows:

Left column (clockwise):

- Jiraiya
- Minato
- Kushina
- Shikamaru, Ino, Chouji

Middle column (clockwise):

- Hinata, Kiba, Shino
- Lee, Tenten, Gai (charred by the 8 Gates), Neji
- Gaara (Fifth Kazekage), A (Fourth Raikage), Bee, Tsunade (Fifth Hokage), Mei (Fifth Mizukage),  Ohnoki (Third Tsuchikage)
- Hiruzen (Third Hokage), Iruka, Konohamaru

Right column (clockwise):

- Sai, Yamato
- Obito
- Kakashi
- Sakura

Answer (score 0):

**I.
Jiraya**

> Jiraiya (自来也) was one of Konohagakure's Sannin and teacher of Naruto.

[image][image: ![enter image description here]

**II.**(*put the name here*) and (*put the name here*)

> *Description*

[image]

**III.**(*put the names here*)

> *Description*

[image]

**IV.**(*put the names here*)

> *Description*

[image]

**V.**(*put the names here*)

> *Description*

[image]

Comment: Please maintain the format while editing.

Comment: I assume it has something to do with Ashura being the one that relies on others for power. Naruto got this far because of them, they are the source of his power, and he is fighting for them. I believe this is the first regular rasengan he makes with only one hand as well, so I bet there is something there too, how he could never do this alone, looping back to them being his power. What is actually going on, no idea. It could just be a way for him to do the other half of the rasengan without the clone, showing his growth.

Comment: I would say it's a pain in the ass to identify the characters by just a tiny part of their sleeves or gloves.

Comment: @HappyFace I could only recognise Jiraiya, Minato, Rock Lee, Killer Bee, and Kakashi's hands, and that's only because of what they have on their hands. But yeah, it would be a pain in the ass to recognise ALL of them!

Comment: Actually he had made a regular rasengan earlier in the fight against sasuke after they fell from the sky. He tripped though and it exploded on the ground then sasuke kicked him in the face, but he did make one without a shadow clone. This leads me to think that he has been able to do so for quite some time but maybe he prefersto use the clone out of habit?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what this scene means is that Naruto's strength comes from all the people he loved and who have been there in his life at every trouble for him. I'm not really sure of the order of the ones who contributed, but here's my guess: Jiraiya, Minato, Kushina, Shikamaru's team, Shino's team, Guy's team, some from Kumogakure, Bee, Tsunade, etc, etc...basically the point is, all of Naurto's bonds who, even in the last moment, stay by his side to protect him.